# Bounded operator with unbounded inverse. Is it (not) open/closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume we have the operator $T:L^1([1,\infty))\to L^1([1,\infty))$ given by:
$$
(Tf)(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}.
$$
It is clear that $\| T\| \leq 1$ and hence is bounded. For the inverse (defined on the image), however, we get an unbounded operator, as can be seen using the sequence of functions $f_n=\frac{2}{n^2}\chi_{(1,n+1)}$ (One has $\|f_n\|\to 0$ but $\|T^{-1}f_n\|>1$ so it can't be bounded). My question is if can we conclude directly from that whether  "$T$ is (not) open or $T$ is (not) closed" (likely invoking closed graph or open mapping, or its corollaries).

Thanks all in advance,

Comment: Since $T$ is injective, it follows directly that it cannot be open (not even as a map to its image with the subspace topology), since a continuous open bijection is a homeomorphism. If "closed" means that it maps closed sets to closed sets, the same argument applies.

Comment: Just a suggestion about LaTeX: for the norm, use `\|` instead of `\mid\mid`.

Comment: @ Daniel: many thanks.

Comment: @Silvia: Thanks, appreciate it. And thanks for the editing then!